# Filepicker Connection Limit

Tags: web-services, amazon-s3, filepicker.io, filepicker

So we have a large amount of images stored on filepicker. It uses S3 as its storage point and we were not storing the s3 file location within our DB, so we need to do a mass GET to retrieve the information. The question I have is we have set up a script to grab each s3 filename one at a time. We are just worried about hitting a connection limit or DDOS prevention software. We have planned on trying it at 200ms intervals to ease this but has anyone else encountered a similar situation or know of what the connection limit is?

Answer (score 0):

According to an email from Filepicker support. 200ms between calls is a safe interval.